# Why does setting an input value to undefined not empty it?

Tags: javascript, input

As demonstrated in the following example:

```js
document.getElementById('test1').value = null;
document.getElementById('test2').value = undefined;
```

```html
<input id="test1" value="DEFAULT TEXT" />
<input id="test2" value="DEFAULT TEXT" />
```

An input's value is reset whenever it is set to `null`, but why doesn't it also reset when it is set to `undefined`?
 How come it sets the value to the string `"undefined"` instead?

Comment: it takes strings use strings instead. like `... = ''`

Comment: That's how it is [defined](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#htmlinputelement) for the `value` property of the `HTMLInputElement`: `[TreatNullAs=EmptyString] attribute DOMString value;`

Comment: @andreas thats the first real answer to the question (unfortuantely posted as a comment) :)

Comment: For those who are voting to close as "too broad": the answers seem pretty concise and on-point.

Comment: @JonasWilms Feel free to adopt it into your answer :)

Comment: @Andreas Now that is the clarity I needed, this should definitely be an answer.

Comment: @federico not even that, the question is not broad in any way, there is probably a good dupe somewhere on SO that no one is able to find, but this is definetly not to broad...

Comment: @EternalDarkness It's now in Jonas answer. No need for another one^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.value` is a string and expects a string, so the correct way to empty it would be to use an empty string:

```
 /*...*/.value = "";
```

Assigning `undefined` will cause it to be stringified, which results in `"undefined"`, whereas `null` cannot be stringified, therefore the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#htmlinputelement) says, that assigning `null` to `.value` will be like using an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

`undefined` means a variable has been declared but has not yet been assigned a value.

On the other hand, `null` is an assignment value. It can be assigned to a variable as a representation of no value.

Comment: `undefined` can also be assigned to a value, as `undefined` is a global variable being underined.

Comment: Properties and variables can be assigned the value of undefined. It’s what the OP is specifically asking about. But in most situations setting the “value” of an INPUT DOM element to undefined will result in it being cast to a String. The only difference here is the outcome of the cast between null and undefined. I think this answer adds more confusion than it helps.